# Creating a really large shapefile without eating all the virtual memory

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, pyshp

I am doing something similar to below to create a really large (large than memory on my machine) shapefile:

```
shapes = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
shapes.autoBalance = 1
shapes.field('MyId','N')
shapes.field('OtherData','C', 20)

for item in largeIteration():
    . . . . .
    shapes.record(item['id'], item['desc'])
    shapes.point(item['lat'], item['lon'])
```

The problem is while I'm using `yield` in `largeIteration()` to not hold onto memory there, the entire shapefile seems to remain open in memory, and therefore `shapes` grows with each call to `shapes.record() and shapes.point().` Is there any way I can have pyshape not hold the entire shape in memory? I see OGR and its virtual file systems. However, I don't see a "stream to disk" vfs option.

Comment: If you've got a virtual shapefile which is using too much RAM, it's not likely that you *could* write it to disk (2Gb limit)

Comment: Could you create shapefiles of a limited size that are within your memory constraints.  You can always merge them later if you need a unified shapefile.  But it would be better to segment your data anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To process large files, you need to use a generator which only read/write one line at a time and Python has a command that does that: [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

> The with statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The for line in f treats the file object f as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files. ([How to read large file, line by line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133))

In short

```
with open("my_large_file.shp", "w") as f:
    for line in f:
       (code here)
```

Illustration with a Python module that allows that, [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html), with data from [where do I append point values with pyshp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13406974)

```
data = [(33.21, -122.15, 'France'), (35.31, -122.15, 'Germany'), (35.41, -123.15, 'Hawaii'), (30.51, -122.15, 'Philippines'),(32.30, -122.15, 'Texas')]

import fiona
# schema of the shapefile
schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'location':'str:20'}
with fiona.open('my_shapefile.shp', 'w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema) as output:
    for i in data:
        point = {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (l[0],l[1])}
        prop = {'location': l[2]}
        output.write({'geometry': point, 'properties':prop})
```

The equivalent solution with Pyshp leads to an error `AttributeError: Writer instance has no attribute '__exit__`
:

```
 with sf.Writer(sf.POINT) as w:
    w.field('location','C', 20))
    for l in data:
       w.point(l[0], l[1])
       w.record(l[2])
       w.save("my_shapefile.shp")
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use directly `with` here because PyShp,by design, "constructs' the entire shapefile in memory before saving it (but can use `with` or `yield`to read a shapefile, look at [PyShp as Fiona (with the GeoJSON-like protocol)](https://github.com/mlaloux/PyShp-as-Fiona--with-geo_interface-)).

```
  w = sf.Writer(sf.POINT)
  w.field('location','C', 20)
  for l in data:
      w.point(l[0], l[1])
      w.record(l[2])
```

and w grows, grows ...(it remain open in memory)
Then

```
   w.save("my_shapefile.shp")
```

You may be try to append each feature to an existing shapefile as in [Appending using PyShp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72421/appending-using-pyshp) but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

this may be old - and i'm likely way off base, but pretty sure i did this a few days ago with OGR to create a shapefile larger than 2Gigs (by checking memory usage during writing, it never seemed to exceed about 40 megs).

so, it would be something like:

```
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = drv.CreateDataSource('myshapefile.shp')
lyr = ds.CreateLayer('myshp', geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint25D)

fieldDef = ogr.FieldDefn('MyID', ogr.OFTInteger)
lyr.CreateField(fieldDef)
fieldDef = ogr.FieldDefn('OtherData', ogr.OFTString)
lyr.CreateField(fieldDef)

for item in largeIteration():
    feat = ogr.Feature(lyr.GetLayerDefn())
    feat.SetField('MyID',item['id'])
    pt = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint25D)
    pt.AddPoint(item['lon'], item['lat'])
    feat.SetGeometry(pt)
    lyr.CreateFeature(feat)

    feat = None
```

i think the 'CreateFeature' writes to disk during each iteration, thus keeping memory usage down.